# Inserting X in its correct position in a sorted list while reading

Tags: prolog, insertion-sort

I tried a lot to think how I can add a value in a sorted list while reading, and I didn't figure it out.

I must read from a file, line by line, values and add them in the correct position in a sorted list.

SWI-PROLOG

If i have input.txt :
1.
4.
2.
3.
8.
6.

I must read 1 put in list 1. 
Read 4 --> my list is 1 4 .
Read 2 ---> my list is 1 2 4 .. and so on .

Read and insert functions :

```
main :-open('input.txt', read, Str),read_file(Str,Lines),close(Str),write(Lines), nl.

read_file(Stream,[]) :-at_end_of_stream(Stream).

read_file(Stream,[X|L]) :-\+ at_end_of_stream(Stream),read(Stream,X),read_file(Stream,L).

insert(X,[Y|Sorted],[Y|Sorted1]):-X>Y,!,insert(X,Sorted,Sorted1).
insert(X,Sorted,[X|Sorted]).
```

I tried to make a function to read(Stream,X) and pass X to insert(X,[],[]), or place in read_file functions List parameters (and get undefined for sure). Logically 1st step is ok, but i didn't figure out how i pass to the next step. No ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write this way

```
read_file(Stream, SoFar, Result) :-
    read(Stream, X),
    (   X == end_of_file
    ->  Result = SoFar
    ;   insert(X, SoFar, Updated),
        read_file(Stream, Updated, Result)
    ).
```

must be called initially with an empty list:

```
?- read_file(user, [], L).
|: 4.
|: 5.
|: 1.
|: 7.
|: 2.
|: L = [1, 2, 4, 5, 7].
```

after the 2 I entered ^D (end_of_file on my system)

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to modify `read_file` to take an input *and* an output. Then, you need to modify this clause:

```
read_file(Stream,[X|L]) :-\+ at_end_of_stream(Stream),read(Stream,X),read_file(Stream,L).
```

To call `insert` and not prepend the item itself. You might do that like this:

```
read_file(Stream, Before, Result) :-
  \+ at_end_of_stream(Stream),
  read(Stream, X),
  insert(X, Before, After),
  read_file(Stream, After, Result).
```